# .Net.Mail new line

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I am using .Net.Mail to send text messages but I am having trouble inserting a new line.  I have searched the internet, including StackOverflow, for a method to do this.  I have found several but non of them work.  I am using StringBuilder to build the body of the message but appending a new line or empty line does cause a new line to be inserted into the message.  I have also tried "\n" and several other methods but nothing seems to work.  I have added my code below.  Does anybody know how I can do this.
Thank you in advance for any help that may be offered.

```
string cellPhone = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CellPhone"));
string suffix = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Suffix"));
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
cellPhone = cellPhone.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
if (!suffix.StartsWith("@"))
{
    suffix = "@" + suffix;
}
string address = cellPhone + suffix;
reader.Close();

EMail email = new EMail("mail.yyy.com");
email.IsHTML = true;
email.Subject = "Sales Lead from yyy.com";
email.Add_ToAddress(address, false);
body.AppendLine(" ");
body.AppendLine("Name: " + this.tbSalesLeadName2.Text + "EMail: mailto: " + this.tbSalesLeadEmail2.Text);

if (!this.chkSalesLeadEmail2.Checked)  //&& (!this.hidCellPhoneProvider.Value.Equals("0", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    body.AppendLine("Phone: " + this.tbSalesLeadPhone2.Text);
    body.AppendLine("Cell Phone: " + this.tbSalesLeadCellPhone.Text);
}

body.AppendLine(" ");
body.AppendLine(" ");
body.AppendLine("Comments: " + this.tbSalesLeadComments2.Text);
body.AppendLine(" ");
body.AppendLine(" ");
body.AppendLine("***To respond start a new text thread with the cell phone number listed above");
email.Body = body.ToString();
email.From = "xxx@yyy.com";
email.Send_Mail();
```

Comment: `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: why not if that were added to the Stringbuilder using AppendFormat() method I believe it would I use Environment.NewLine all the time so not sure why you say it won't help Servy and I am quite aware that `</br>` will work as well if email.IsHTML = true;\\

Comment: @DJKRAZE It's not going to be any different than just using a string literal of the new line character.  It'll literally render the exact same string.  It doesn't even make sense in context; the email isn't even going to necessarily even be rendered on the same machine as the one writing the message; the rendering client could very well be using a different new line character (although most sensible email clients would render any common new line sequence appropriately).

Comment: True but what defines most or sensible.. thanks for your comment

Comment: @DJKRAZE Let's just say I haven't seen an email client that can't render a plain text email using a new line sequence it doesn't expect, but even if you find one, you still wouldn't have solved the problem because the machine reading the email isn't necessarily the same machine as the one writing it.

Comment: then explain to me how all of our email messages going out to our end users in the company render the same and correctly using .net to create and send emails..??? anyway I am not going to get all worked up over the back and forth on this topic ..

Answer (score 6):

```
email.IsHTML = true;
```

You say that your body is in HTML format, but it isn't.

You have two options to fix that:

1. Set `IsHTML` to false, and your line breaks should work.
2. Format your body as *real* HTML, i.e., use `HtmlEncode` for your data and `<br>` for your line breaks.

Comment: Looks like he does actually have some HTML code in that message.

Comment: There's a `mailto`, which it seems like he wants to be rendered as a link.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, yes. But that won't work without proper `<a href=...>` etc. around it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using email.IsHTML = true;, You should be able to put 
 tag in your string builder object.. The code would look like,

```
body.AppendLine(" <br/>");
body.AppendLine(" <br/>");
body.AppendLine("Comments: " + this.tbSalesLeadComments2.Text + "<br/>");
body.AppendLine(" <br/>");
body.AppendLine(" <br/>");
body.AppendLine("***To respond start a new text thread with the cell phone number listed above<br/>");
email.Body = body.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've specified that the email is HTML.  New lines are ignored in HTML.

To actually render a line break you need to use `<br />` or some other equivalent.

If you don't actually have any HTML to render, then simply specify that the email is not an HTML email and new lines will be rendered as new lines.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried both suggestions, unfortunately neither worked.  The messages came out looking exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice.  Please ignore my earlier comment.  Your suggestion did work I just needed to add "\n" where I wanted a new line.
I really appreciate your help.